# how to generate a grid of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I want to build a function `GridGen`, so that it does the following.

```
GridGen([a], -1, 1) --> [{a: -1}, {a: 0}, {a: -1}]
GridGen([a, b], -1, 1) --> [{a: -1, b: -1},{a: 0, b: -1}, {a: 1, b: -1},
                            {a: -1, b: 0}, {a: 0, b: 0}, {a: 1, b: 0}, 
                            {a: -1, b: 1}, {a: 0, b: 1}, {a: 1, b: 1}]
GridGen([a,b,c], -1, 1) --> [{a: -1, b: -1, c: -1},{a: 0, b: -1, c: -1}, {a: 1, b: -1, c:-1}, ... ]
```

At the moment I achieve this with two functions with a simple recursion.

```
from sage.all import *
def TensorMergeDict(dicts):
    if len(dicts) == 2:
        return flatten([[dicts[0][i] | dicts[1][j] for i in range(len(dicts[0]))] for j in range(len(dicts[1]))])
    else:
        print(TensorMergeDict([dicts[0], TensorMergeDict(dicts[1:])]))
        return

def GridGen(vars, minV, maxV, step = 1):
    dicts = [[{e: i} for i in range(minV, maxV + 1, step)] for e in vars]
    return TensorMergeDict(dicts)
```

where `sage` provides the convenient `flatten` function to flatten a list.

I wonder if there is better/efficient way to do it? It feels like there should be some existing function in `Python` or `SageMath` that facilitates such operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `itertools.product`? -

```py
from itertools import product

def grid(keys, lo, hi):
  for p in product(range(lo, hi + 1), repeat=len(keys)):
    yield {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, p)}
        
for x in grid("abc", -1, 1):
  print(x)
```

```py
{'a': -1, 'b': -1, 'c': -1}
{'a': -1, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}
{'a': -1, 'b': -1, 'c': 1}
{'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1}
{'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
{'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
{'a': -1, 'b': 1, 'c': -1}
{'a': -1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
{'a': -1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
{'a': 0, 'b': -1, 'c': -1}
{'a': 0, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}
{'a': 0, 'b': -1, 'c': 1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': -1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': -1}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': -1, 'c': -1}
{'a': 1, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': -1, 'c': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': -1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': -1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0}
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
```

`keys` can be string or array -

```py
for x in grid(["foo", "bar"], -1, 1):
  print(x)
```

```py
{'foo': -1, 'bar': -1}
{'foo': -1, 'bar': 0}
{'foo': -1, 'bar': 1}
{'foo': 0, 'bar': -1}
{'foo': 0, 'bar': 0}
{'foo': 0, 'bar': 1}
{'foo': 1, 'bar': -1}
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 0}
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
```